# *Swift* Expected to decode Array<Any> but found a dictionary instead

Tags: arrays, swift, api, dictionary

FIXED: Larme's last response fixed the issue, had to change a few other things.

I am already prepared to be reamed for asking a question to which many have already asked on here. However, I've given all the solutions I've found a try but none have worked for my particular application...or I am just royally screwing this up.

I've taken the array brackets off of *var mealList = TopMeal* and *decode([TopMeal].self* (on the ViewController) like many of you fine people have suggested although that gives me an additional error.. I've watched a number of YouTube videos, read forums, went to bed, did it all again, and here I am.

Anyways here is the API I'm using [API](https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/filter.php?c=Dessert)

Error message:

```
2022-05-11 14:53:59.766132-0500 FetchRewardsTest[7861:5585317] [boringssl] boringssl_metrics_log_metric_block_invoke(151) Failed to log metrics
typeMismatch(Swift.Array<Any>, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Array<Any> but found a dictionary instead.", underlyingError: nil))
2022-05-11 15:31:41.102003-0500 FetchRewardsTest[7861:5586629] [ServicesDaemonManager] interruptionHandler is called. -[FontServicesDaemonManager connection]_block_invoke
```

Here are my structs:

```
struct TopMeal: Codable {
    var topMeal: Meals
}

//struct for base meal details
struct Meals: Codable {
    var strMeal: String?
    var strMealThumb: String?
    var idMeal: String?

}
```

Here is the rest of the jazz.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    
    var mealList = [TopMeal]()

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        getApiData {
            print("data loaded")
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return mealList.count
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: nil)
        cell.textLabel?.text = "\(mealList[indexPath.row])"
        return cell
    }
    
    
    
    
//    MealApi.shared.getApiData(onCompletion: anonFunction)
    func getApiData(completed: @escaping () -> ()) {
        let url = URL(string: "https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/filter.php?c=Dessert")
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
            
            if error == nil {
                do {
                    self.mealList = try JSONDecoder().decode([TopMeal].self, from: data!)
                   
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        completed()
                    }
                }
                catch {
                    print(error)
                }
            }
        }.resume()
        
    }
}
```

Any help at all would be much appreciated.

Comment: `[TopMeal].self` => `TopMeal.self`, your JSON is a Dictionary at top level, not an array, and, then `var topMeal: Meals` => `var topMeal: [Meals]`, that'd be a good start. But show FULL error, it give important info on why it fails and where...

Comment: var topMeal: [Meals], try this in model, and change decode to TopMeal.self

Comment: And then `var mealList = [TopMeal]()` -> `var mealList = [Meal]()`

Comment: Updated with error message, forgot to include it!

Comment: `struct TopMeal: Codable { let meals: [Meals] }`

Comment: @Larme Changing [TopMeal].self -> TopMeal.self throws this error -- Cannot assign value of type 'TopMeal' to type '[Meals]' same applies if I make it Meals.self

Comment: Anything beyond changing the struct that you can see @JoakimDanielson ? I've changed everything that's been mentioned to only get the error I listed above.

Comment: `let topMeal = try JSONDecoder().decode(TopMeal.self, from: data!); self.mealList = topMeal.topMeal`

Comment: @Larme Changing that I get `Value of type 'TopMeal' has no member 'TopMeal'`         This was the direction I was heading though. It seems the variable I made at the top `var mealList = [Meal]()` is having some communication issues or something..    Also I appreciate you responding, gives me some hope,lol.

Comment: I had to change a few other things but the last thing @Larme suggested fixed it. Thank you very much!!